# ¿Como sumar +1 uno a un Nombre en caso de registro repetido?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una columna llamada `NOMBRE`. En esta hay tres pacientes llamados "Juan". Lo que quiero es distinguirlos agregándole un número seguido después de su nombre. Algo así:

```
Juan1
```

O si hubieran 30252 registros llamados Juan, poner:

```
Juan30252
```

Hice esto pero no va en orden de Registro:

```
SELECT Paciente, COUNT(Paciente) AS Dupenumber 
            INTO #Cambiado
            FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
            GROUP BY Paciente 
            HAVING ( COUNT(Paciente) > 1 )

            UPDATE PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
            SET Paciente = Paciente + CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(NEWID()))AS VARCHAR)  
            WHERE Paciente in (SELECT Paciente FROM #Cambiado)

            DROP Table #Cambiado
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que estás usando SQL Server 2005+, puedes usar `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Paciente ORDER BY Paciente),
            N = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Paciente)
    FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Paciente =  Paciente + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(20)) 
WHERE N > 1;
```

Haciendo la consulta de esta forma te evitas tener que crear una tabla temporal con los registros de pacientes duplicados.